# Removing specific items from array with MongoDB

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing a web app using Codeigniter and MongoDB.
The users can upload files and other users can comment on them.

I store the comments in an array called comments in the main file document.
This is all fine but how can I remove specific comments from the array?

I cannot use ID as key since a user can add multiple comments. How would
you recommend that I can do it?

This is my comment array:

```
"comments": [
        {
            "user_id": ObjectId("4f240b433dc7937d68030000"),
            "user_name": "james",
            "user_comment": "This is a comment",
            "created_at": "2012-01-2821: 20: 44"
        },
        {
            "user_id": ObjectId("4f240b433dc7937d68030000"),
            "user_name": "mandy",
            "user_comment": "This is another comment",
            "created_at": "2012-01-2821: 31: 07"
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 60):

If you can identify the comment item by matching userid, name or comment -- then you can remove that comment using `update()` command with `$pull` modifier along with the appropriate condition.

If you cannot do as above, include an unique id in the comments (like `UUID`).

To delete the comment, do the following:

```
db.coll.update({<cond to identify document}, {$pull: {'comments': {'name': <name>}}} )
```

If you use the id, which is preferred:

```
db.coll.update({<cond to identify document}, {$pull: {'comments': {'id': <id>}}} )
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can I let mongoDB assign a UUID? If yes, how?

Comment: Nope. For values within your document, as in this case, you need to generate UUID. PHP has uniqid(), which you can also use.

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. The docs on this one are lackluster.

Comment: but how can I add an index for the fields in an object of an array?

Comment: Can you show how we can do this using Linq for Mongo DB c# ?

Comment: this is how you can do it in c#,  Update.Pull("comments", Query.EQ("_id", new ObjectId(feeId)));

Answer (score 4):

maybe you can remove comment by its '`created_at`' time, as the time is unique.

```
$db.coll.update({cond to identify document},{$pull:{'comments':{'created_at':<>}}})
```

Comment: Multiple users can post in the same second, though, so i'd generate a unique id for each comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have add mongodb id to each comment when insert it. You can create a new mongodb id like this;

```
$comment_id = new MongoID();
```

Now, you can delete comments by id with $pull + $update like @smoorthy's answer.