# How can I delete a data from nested collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I delete a nested collection, for example below, I want to delete id 50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd2 from Pic?

Data:

```
{
    "_id": "50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd1",
    "Name": "Bubba",
    "Address": "1111",
    "Pic" : [{"_id": "50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd2", "Name": "test1.jpg", "Size":"1000"}, {"_id": "50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd3",. "Name": "test2.jpg", "Size":"2000"}],
    "LastModified": {
        "$date": "2012-12-21T03:47:26.535Z"
    }
}
```

---

Solved with $pull:

db.coll.update({}, {$pull: {'things': {'myval': 1}}});

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048424/removing-specific-items-from-array-with-mongodb

Comment: Just tried it, it works now. tq.

Comment: For completeness you should add this as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.collection.update( criteria, objNew, upsert, multi )

```
db.collection.update( { "_id": "50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd1" }, { $unset : { "Pic._id" : 1 } }, false, true);
```

Remember to use the multi option as true if you want to update multiple records.

**UPDATE**

To make it work, we should change criteria in a such way

```
{ "Pic._id": "50d3dbce1292dd2e98af1dd2" }
```

Or to use `$pull` as Kev said:

```
db.coll.update({}, {$pull: {'things': {'myval': 1}}});
```

Comment: This would work if `pic` was an embedded document. In the question, it is an array and this operation has no effect.

Comment: I think have to use $pull instead of $unset. Let me try it.