# MongoDB, remove object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Doc:

```
{
   _id: 5150a1199fac0e6910000002,
   name: 'some name',
   items: [{
      id: 23,
      name: 'item name 23'
   },{
      id: 24,
      name: 'item name 24'
   }]
}
```

Is there a way to pull a specific object from an array?  I.E. how do I pull the entire item object with id 23 from the items array.

I have tried:

```
db.mycollection.update({'_id': ObjectId("5150a1199fac0e6910000002")}, {$pull: {id: 23}});
```

However I am pretty sure that I am not using 'pull' correctly.  From what I understand pull will pull a field from an array but not an object.

Any ideas how to pull the entire object out of the array.

As a bonus I am trying to do this in mongoose/nodejs, as well not sure if this type of thing is in the mongoose API but I could not find it.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048424/removing-specific-items-from-array-with-mongodb

Answer (score 212, accepted):

try..

```
db.mycollection.update(
    { '_id': ObjectId("5150a1199fac0e6910000002") }, 
    { $pull: { items: { id: 23 } } },
    false, // Upsert
    true, // Multi
);
```

Comment: yup, my syntax was wrong.  Thanks!  Also tried without the upset and multi options and that worked as well.

Comment: What are those boolean values?

Comment: @NicolasDelValle if I remember correctly, these were options 
 `upsert` and `multi`. For current syntax & documentation check this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Answer (score 13):

I have a document like

[image]

I have to delete address from address array

After searching lots on internet I found the solution

```
Customer.findOneAndUpdate(query, { $pull: {address: addressId} }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'error in deleting address' });
    }

    res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: How to do this in MongoDB CLI ?

Comment: I think this is nodejs (express) solution not the MongoDB query solution

Answer (score 8):

my database:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5806056dce046557874d3ab18"),
  "data" : [ 
    { "id" : 1 }, 
    { "id" : 2 }, 
    { "id" : 3 }
  ]
}
```

my query:

```
db.getCollection('play_table').update({},{$pull:{"data":{"id":3}}},{multi:true}
```

output:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5806056dce046557874d3ab18"),
  "data" : [ 
    { "id" : 1 }, 
    { "id" : 2 }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try it also:

```
db.getCollection('docs').update({ },{'$pull':{ 'items':{'id': 3 }}},{multi:true})
```

Answer (score 6):

For a single record in array:

```
db.getCollection('documents').update(
    { },
    {'$pull':{ 'items':{'mobile': 1234567890 }}},
    {new:true}
);
```

For a multiple records with same mobile number in array:

```
db.getCollection('documents').update(
    { },
    {
        $pull: {
            items: { mobile: 1234567890 }
        }
    },
    { new:true, multi:true }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$pull` to remove the data

```
return this.mobiledashboardModel
.update({"_id": args.dashboardId}, { $pull: {"viewData": { "_id": widgetId}}})
.exec()
.then(dashboardDoc => {
     return {
        result: dashboardDoc
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Kishore Diyyana:

If you want to remove all elements including the key of the element attributes list.

Here is the example of mongoDB unset operator:

```
db.UM_PREAUTH_CASE.update(
{ 'Id' : 123}, { $unset: { dataElements: ""} } )
```

JSON Look like this:

```
{ "Id":123,"dataElements" : [ { "createdBy" : "Kishore Babu Diyyana", "createdByUserId" : 2020 }, { "createdBy" : "Diyyana Kishore", "createdByUserId" : 2021 } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Very simple way to do this:-

Sample data that I used is:-
{
            "_id": "6419606109433f61b50dfaa4",
            "category": "SUV",
            "vehicles": [
                {
                    "id": "18d527aa-948e-40bc-9ce1-c54dc04a6350"
                    "name": "Honda City 4th Generation",
                    "average": "23.26 kmpl",
                    "cc": "1197 cc",
                    "seat": "5 Seater",
                },
{
                    "id": "18d527aa-948e-40bc-9ce1-c54dc04a6349"
                    "name": "Honda City 4th Generation",
                    "average": "23.26 kmpl",
                    "cc": "1197 cc",
                    "seat": "5 Seater",
                },
}

exports.delete_vehicle = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id, vuuid } = req.params;
  const vehicle = await VehicleCategory.find({ _id: id });
  try{
    for(let i = 0; i < vehicle[0].vehicles.length; i++){
      if(vehicle[0].vehicles[i].id === vuuid){
        await VehicleCategory.findByIdAndUpdate(
          {_id:id},
          { $pull: { vehicles: { id: vuuid } } },
          { new: true }
        );
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Vehicle deleted successfully."
        });
      }else{
        res.status(404).json({
          message: "The given id is not found."
        });
      }
    }
  }catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  }
  

};
```

router.put("/deleteVehicle/:id/:vuuid", userController.delete_vehicle);