# Mongoose deleting (pull) a document within an array, does not work with ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
user = {
    "userId" : "myId",
    "connections":
    [{
        "dateConnectedUnix": 1334567891,
        "isActive": true
    }, {
        "dateConnectedUnix": 1334567893,
        "isActive": false
    }]
}
```

I would like to delete the second item in the `connections` array, to get the following:

```
user = {
    "userId" : "myId",
    "connections": 
    [{
        "dateConnectedUnix": 1334567893,
        "isActive": false
    }]
}
```

The following code does the job as expected:

```
userAccounts.update(
    { 'connections.isActive': false }, 
    { $pull: { 'connections.isActive':false }}, 
    function (err, val) {
        console.log(val)
    }
);
```

But, I need to delete based on ObjectId.  And the following goes does not work:

```
userAccounts.update(
    { 'connections._id': '1234-someId-6789' }, 
    { $pull: { 'connections._id': '1234-someId-6789' } },
    function (err, val) {
        console.log(val)
    }
);
```

Any suggestions? I have been banging my head against the screen (aka Google, Stackoverflow, ...) for hours and have had no luck.

Comment: Can someone help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124014/removing-object-with-objectid-from-array-in-mongoose-mongodb/49126608#49126608 Similar problem :(

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It seems that the above code would not work.  It should not even have worked for the first example I gave.

In the end I was supported by this answer here: [MongoDB, remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array)

Here is my working code:

```
userAccounts.update( 
    { userId: usr.userId },
    {
        $pull: {
            connections: { _id : connId }
        }
    },
    { safe: true },
    function removeConnectionsCB(err, obj) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

Comment: and `connId` and `usr.userId` is an instanceof `ObjectId`?

Comment: I thought `safe: true` was set by default?

Answer (score 22):

I have a document like

[image]

I have to delete address from address array

After searching lots on internet I found the solution

```
Customer.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$pull: {address: addressId}}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'error in deleting address' });
    }
    res.json(data);   
});
```

Comment: Exactly same problem but doesn't work for me. What version of mongodb is this?

Comment: What was your query and route url ? What if it is dynamic in `addressId`

Comment: you should do the update query like this 
`Customer.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$pull: {address:  mongoose.Type.ObjectId(addressId)}}, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'error in deleting address' });
    }
    res.json(data);   
});`

Answer (score 11):

```
user: {
 _id: ObjectId('5ccf3fa47a8f8b12b0dce204'),
 name: 'Test',
 posts: [
  ObjectId("5cd07ee05c08f51af8d23b64"),
  ObjectId("5cd07ee05c08f51af8d23c52")
 ]
}
```

Remove a single post from posts array

`user.posts.pull("5cd07ee05c08f51af8d23b64");
 user.save();`

Comment: **The best specially if you're updating a found document.**

Comment: same thing didn't work for me, no err, just didn't work, any clue??

Answer (score 10):

To use update with ObjectId, you should use ObjectId object instead of string representation :

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

userAccounts.update(
    { 'connections._id': new ObjectId('1234-someId-6789') }, 
    { $pull: { 'connections._id': new ObjectId('1234-someId-6789') } }, 
    function (err,val) {
        console.log(val)
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Technically, I think you are right.  But I was actually referencing my code using the valid ObjectId JSON format.  I have posted my own answer.

Comment: I think your code is a little bit misleading.  For instance in line 3, you wrote `connections_.id` when in fact the original question clearly shows that `connections` is an array of objects with no `_id` property attached to it.

Answer (score 7):

### use `findByIdAndUpdate` to remove an item from an array

You can do it in **`mongoose 5.4.x and above`**

```
const result = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user_id, {
    $pull: {
        someArrayName: { _id: array_item_id }
    }
}, { new: true });
```

The item from array will be removed based on provided property `_id` value

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `mongoose`, no need to use the `MongoDB` stuff, I mean that's why we're using `mongoose` in the first place, right?

```js
userAccounts.connections.pull({ _id: '1234-someId-6789'});
await userAccounts.save();
```

Answer (score 1):

mongoose: 4.11.11
What have worked for me is the following syntax:

```
const removeTansactionFromUser = (userId, connectionId) => {
    return User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, { $pull: { "connections": connectionId} }, {'new': true} );
};
```

Mongoose support id in string format or ObjectId format.
Tip: `new ObjectId(stringId)` to switch from string to ObjectId

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose 5.8.11, this `$pull: { ... }` didn't work for me, so far not sure why. So I overcame it in my controller this way:

```
exports.removePost = async (req, res, next) => {
  const postId = req.params.postId;
  try {
    const foundPost = await Post.findById(postId);
    const foundUser = await User.findById(req.userId);
    if (!foundPost || !foundUser) {
      const err = new Error(
        'Could not find post / user.',
      );
      err.statusCode = 404;
      throw err;
    }
    // delete post from posts collection:
    await Post.findByIdAndRemove(postId);
    // also delete that post from posts array of id's in user's collection:
    foundUser.posts.pull({ _id: postId });
    await foundUser.save();
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Deleted post.' });
  } catch (err) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you use the pull method with syntax: `$pull: {propertyId: _id}` with  `_id` can be found from a document, ensure that _id is string type if not using the method `toString()` to convert to string type. Let's check it!