# $pull seems to just set an element to null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to setup a delete button where a lesson can be deleted from a class. Using $pull seems to just set lesson_id to null though. Is there a way to remove that element completely?

```
var classSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    lessons: [{
        _id: false,
        lesson_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Lesson'}
    }]
});

module.exports.deleteLesson = function(class_id, lesson_id, callback){
    Class.update(
        {'_id': class_id}, 
        { $pull: {lessons: {'lesson_id.$._id': lesson_id}}},
        callback
    )
}
```

For example

```
{ _id: 5808,
  title: 'cd',
  __v: 0,
  lessons: [ { lesson_id: [Object] }, { lesson_id: [Object] } ] }
```

becomes

```
{ _id: 5808,
  title: 'cd',
  __v: 0,
  lessons: [ { lesson_id: null }, { lesson_id: [Object] } ] }
```

Comment: Maybe this might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/20275454/2931650

Comment: I don't think $ is the correct operator in this case, instead pullAll should be used so what if you use { $pull: {lessons: {'lesson_id._id': lesson_id}}} or on a hunch { $pull: {lessons: {'lesson_id': lesson_id}}} ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to delete an element from lessons (which is an array), then you need to just perform the deletion of element from the array and then perform a save operation. I have written code showcasing a similar approach.

```
Class.findOne({ _id: class_id }, function(err, cls) {   

          # Delete the element (for example, using underscore)
          cls.lessons = _.without(cls.lessons, class_id);

              cls.save(function (err) {     
                       callback(err);
             });
    });
```