# Removing object with ObjectId from array in Mongoose/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I go into the _carts array and delete the object with _id of '1'?? Also, am I using the update and $pull right with the ObjectId?? Assuming that the user _id and cart _id are both ObjectIds.

Also user_id and cart_id gives a string of the ids back (and are working). How do I do this?? It's just the query that I'm having trouble with.

Router file

```
const User = require('../models/User');
const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const config = require('../config/dev');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

exports.deletelocalcartproduct = function (req, res, next) {
    const token = req.query.token;
    const secret = config.secret;
    const decoded = jwt.decode(token, secret);

    const user_id = decoded.sub; // THIS IS A STRING

    const cart_id = req.query.cart; // THIS IS A STRING

    // THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    const user = User.update(
        {'_id': ObjectId(user_id)},
        { $pull: { '_carts': { _id: (cart_id) }}},
        false,
        true
    );
    user.save();
}
```

User model

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    _carts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'cart'
    }],
    admin: Boolean
});
```

Cart model

```
const cartSchema = new Schema({
    _product: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'product'
    },
    quantity: Number
});
```

Example seed data

```
const User1 = {
     _id: '1234',
     _carts: [{
              _id: '1',
              _product: {},
              quantity: 2
              }, 
              {
              _id: '2',
              _product: {},
              quantity: 4
              }],
        admin: false
    }
```

Used the corrections from the answers you guys gave me, and I got this error on my terminal:

```
 (node:3042) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client
[0] Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.
[0] (node:3042) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
[0] TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined
[0]     at exports.deletelocalcartproduct (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/controllers/auth.js:76:10)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[0]     at Route.dispatch (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
[0]     at Function.process_params (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[0]     at next (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[0]     at jsonParser (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:118:7)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at trim_prefix (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
[0]     at Function.process_params (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[0]     at next (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[0]     at cors (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
[0] events.js:136
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0] 
[0] TypeError: callback.apply is not a function
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4074:16
[0]     at callback (/Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2981:9)
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/kareem/index.js:213:48
[0]     at /Users/user/Desktop/bootiq/server/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
[0]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

If I find the user and console log:

```
{ _id: 5a9d055cc4587fb6cb36ea99,
[0]   admin: false,
[0]   __v: 4,
[0]   _carts: 
[0]    [ { _id: 5a9d07208537e2b74cbf0c6c,
[0]        _product: [Object],
[0]        quantity: 3,
[0]        __v: 0 },
[0]      { _id: 5a9d120e2398caba6390321e,
[0]        _product: [Object],
[0]        quantity: 2,
[0]        __v: 0 },
[0]      { _id: 5a9d18293df497bcbb580a76,
[0]        _product: [Object],
[0]        quantity: 7,
[0]        __v: 0 } ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here in update function

```
User.update(
        {'_id':user_id}, // you not need to use ObjectId here
        { $pull: { '_carts': { _id: cart_id }}},
        function(err,result){
    // can you give here the output of console.log(result);
   }
    )
    User.save();
```

Comment: can you give the output of `console.log(result)` ?

Comment: The error i got on my terminal is on the post (just updated) and on my console log i got

Comment: createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)

Answer (score 0):

After closely looking at your problem what I found is something wrong with your `User` Model schema. So I have updated the answer accordingly.

In your `User` model the `_carts` filed has following schema you have used.

```
_carts: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'cart'
    }]
```

So as per your schema the array contains `Objectids` which has reference to `cart` model. `(example: _carts:[ObjectId1,ObjectId2,Object3 ....])`

But in your Seed data the document is

```
const User1 = {
     _id: '1234',
     _carts: [{
              _id: '1',
              _product: {},
              quantity: 2
              }, 
              {
              _id: '2',
              _product: {},
              quantity: 4
              }],
        admin: false
    }
```

which has `objects` in `_carts` array. As per schema it should be `ObjectIds` not `Objects`

Now as per your query `{ $pull: { '_carts': { _id: (cart_id) }}}` you are trying to pull the document which has `_id = cart_id`. But there is no `_id` available in your `_carts` schema .

So here is my analysis. If you want store `cart` details in `carts` array. Then your `User` model's schema should be

`_carts : [cartSchema]`

Otherwise your `update` query has no problem. It should work.

The error you have mentioned is due to `mongodb` connection issue. Please follow updated `Mongoose` doc on how to connect Mongodb properly.

Comment: the error is about MongoDB connection. Its saying `.open` is deprecated use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. I am not sure how you are connecting to from Mongoose.

Comment: I have updated the answer have a look and let me know if it helps you @Ckusuma