# MongoDB with Nodejs(Express): Delete a property in a document's array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Assume we have the following collection, which I have a questions about:

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c0798cfa572a912a7d93308"),
 "shop_name" : "Royal Foods",
 "address" : "Colombo",
 `"items" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0798cfa572a912a7d9330d"),
        "item_name" : "Pasta",
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0798cfa572a912a7d9330c"),
        "item_name" : "Noodles",
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0798cfa572a912a7d9330b"),
        "item_name" : "Rice & Curry",
    }  
  ]
}
```

I want to delete the first item which is "Pasta" without deleting the whole document. I want to do this using delete restful API. I use Nodejs and Express for my backend development.
I tried the following:

```
router.delete('/ninjas/:id', function(req,res){
      Shop.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(Shop{
        res.send(Shop);
      });
});
```

But it is deleting the whole collection when I pass the shop id to this api. I only need to delete the "Pasta" food item.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose deleting (pull) a document within an array, does not work with ObjectID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786075/mongoose-deleting-pull-a-document-within-an-array-does-not-work-with-objectid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findByIdAndRemove finds the document and removes it.
It would be better if you had a separate model for Item but whatever, In-order to remove a specific item from the items array in the document you can use the Array filter method.

```
Shop.findById(req.params.id,(err, foundShop) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);

    if(!foundShop) {
        // Shop Doesn't Exists
        res.send('Shop Doesn\'t exist');
    }

    if(foundShop) {
        // Shop Exists
        const filteredItems = foundShop.items.filter(item => item.item_name !== 'Pasta'); // Returns a new Array with the Item Pasta removed.
        foundShop.items = filteredItems;

        foundShop.save();

        res.send('Item has been removed from the array');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using mongoose.

```
Shop.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.id },
  { $pull: item_name: "Pasta" },
  { new: true }
).then(function(Shop{
  res.send(Shop);
});
```

The method `findByIdAndRemove` removes the entire document, as you only want to change it, you should use findOneAndUpdate

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have a syntax error in your router:

```
router.delete('/ninjas/:id', function(req,res){
  Shop.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(Shop{
    res.send(Shop);
  });
});
```

In your promise:

```
.then(function(Shop) { 
   res.send(Shop)
})
```

...would be correct. Hope that helps
But is highly unusual to return that Shop object like that.

```
.then(function(result) { 
    res.send(result)
})
```

...would be a more common patterns

Also, `findbyidandremove` probably does not return the deleted object. You would need to check the online documentation (I'm assuming mongoose)

Comment: This doesn't answer how to pull a register from an array

Answer (score -1):

Check out their documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/#db.collection.deleteOne).

You can create a single file like 'deletePasta.js' and paste the following line.

```
db.{{databaseName}}.deleteOne( { "_id" : ObjectId("5c0798cfa572a912a7d9330d") } );
```

Just insert the databseName at {{databaseName}}

```
mongo {{apiName}} < deletePasta.js
```

Paste that in your console and replace {{apiName}} with the name of your API.

Comment: the person is looking for a way to do this with JavaScript on express, not on the console