# How do I delete an objectId from an array if I only have the ID as a string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have an array of ObjectIDs in Client.users. I am trying to delete the ObjectId that matches the ID stored in the req.body. The ID stored is a string of "5fa0625514b0db02df53084b" - not in an ObjectID format.

```js
 
const { id } = req.body; // this is 5fa0625514b0db02df53084b (second in the array)

Client: {
    users: [
        ObjectId("5fa027c614b0db02df530848"),
        ObjectId("5fa0625514b0db02df53084b") 
    ]
}
```

I have tried converting the string in the req.body to an object ID using Mongoose, but it still doesn't work.

```js
let searchQuery = {"_id": jwt.id};

Client.findOneAndUpdate(searchQuery, {
    $pull: {
        "users": [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)]
    }
})
```

Is it possible to remove an ObjectID from the array, if I only have it as a string to begin with? I know there must be a way to convert it somehow, but the docs told me to use my attempt above, but it doesn't seem to work (doesn't remove the ObjectID from the array).

I'd be grateful if anyone could help. Cheers

Comment: First be sure that your `findOneAndUpdate` really find something. Then maybe take a look here, seems to match your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786075/mongoose-deleting-pull-a-document-within-an-array-does-not-work-with-objectid

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786075/mongoose-deleting-pull-a-document-within-an-array-does-not-work-with-objectid/20275454

Answer (score 0):

There is a little error. When you `pull` you are using an array.

The correct query should be like this:

```js
Client.updateOne(searchQuery,
{
  "$pull": {
    "users": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5fa0625514b0db02df53084b")
  }
})
```

Also, the query should use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jwt.id)` to avoid problems.

Mongo playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zJ1s-gO-qHq)