# Mongoose delete object from array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making a Forum application with my first Node Express Mongo API. Posts have an array of comments, and I am trying to delete a comment, based in it's id.

My method returns without errors, but the comment is never deleted.

Deleting method:

```
 export const deleteComment = async (req, res) => {
    const commentId = req.body._id

    const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)

    const _id = post.id

    try {
        await Post.updateOne(
            { _id },
            {
                $pull:
                {
                    comments: { _id: commentId }
                }
            }
        )
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Success' })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({ error: error.message })
    }

}
```

The model looks like the following:

[image: Posts model]

Previously, when using the updateOne method, it for some reason had issues finding the id of the model to update, but I have now used the same formula as before, so I don't see that as being an issue.

Any guesses of what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose deleting (pull) a document within an array, does not work with ObjectID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786075/mongoose-deleting-pull-a-document-within-an-array-does-not-work-with-objectid)

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov No solution there, what exactly do you suggest me doing?

Comment: Try to console.log(commentId) and console.log(req.params.id) to see if you are getting valid results.