# Why isn't pull removing the element from my mongo array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pull

After the deletion of a chore, (*which is made elsewhere in a separate call*) I would like to remove all the entries in the 'list' that contain a reference to the chore that was deleted.

I have the following staticAssignment schema which contains a reference to the chore.

```
const CP_Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  REF_chore: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'cm_chores' },
  REF_person: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'cm_users' },

  type: { type: String, required: true,  },
  when: [{ type: Number, required: true, }],
});

const StaticAssignmentSchema = new Schema({
  affiliation: { type: String, required: true },

  list: [{ type: CP_Schema }],
});

module.exports = StaticAssignment = mongoose.model('cm_staticassignments', StaticAssignmentSchema);
```

Here is some sample data that can be added to a test
NOTE: there are two entries which contain the chore ID that I want to remove '5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f'.  The third entry should remain untouched.

```
{
  "affiliation": "800_800",
  "list": [
    {
      "when": [
        -1
      ],
      "type": "daily",
      "REF_person": "5e441bd5332359211c0403fb",
      "REF_chore": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
    },
    {
      "when": [
        3
      ],
      "type": "weekly",
      "REF_person": "5e441be9332359211c0403fc",
      "REF_chore": "61a261a4ddd46f623879e8df"
    },
    {
      "when": [
        7,
        14,
        21,
        28
      ],
      "type": "monthly",
      "REF_person": "61880980339cab46cccadd4d",
      "REF_chore": "5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to remove all entries from the "list" using mongo's updateOne with a $pull for the chore ID.  However the mongo DB call is not working as I expect it to work.

```
  var query = { affiliation: '800_800' };
  var pull = { $pull: { list: { $elemMatch: { REF_chore: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5c6f12cf4b19711d1824b16f') } } } };

  var ret = await StaticAssignment.updateOne(query, pull);
```

Here is what I am getting back after the 'updateOne' call is executed:

```
{
  "n": 1,
  "nModified": 0,
  "opTime": {
    "ts": "7037976996000825345",
    "t": 88
  },
  "electionId": "7fffffff0000000000000058",
  "ok": 1,
  "$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": "7037976996000825345",
    "signature": {
      "hash": "+iVghD+zcvGAOak8oAKgNknZGJQ=",
      "keyId": "6977092102253445122"
    }
  },
  "operationTime": "7037976996000825345"
}
```

***Additional info***

Here is a snap shot of my mongo collection showing that REF_chore is an object id:

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the REF_chore values are not actually ObjectIds in your database. Can you confirm that they are?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11641932/marcro - see 'Additional Info" in my question

Answer (score 0):

After reading several posts.. I finally found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32242527/3174075

'elemMatch' is NOT required in the pull

Which lead to this:

```
{ "$pull": { "list": {"REF_chore": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(choreId) }}}
```

which does exactly what I want it to do