# Remove a primitive element from an array in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My document looks like this:

```
{
    _id: "57008339e7537f033b67cf84",
    title: "my title",
    urls: ["1.html", "2.html", "3.html"]
}
```

I want to remove `"2.html"` from `urls`. Referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array) I have tried following code:

```
db.collection("bookmarks").update({_id: "57008339e7537f033b67cf84"}, {$pull: {"urls": {$eq: "2.html"}}}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

But the output is:

```
{ [MongoError: unknown top level operator: $eq]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'unknown top level operator: $eq',
  driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 2,
  errmsg: 'unknown top level operator: $eq' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `$eq` operator:

Just use `{$pull: {"urls": "2.html"}}`

```
db.collection("bookmarks").update({_id: "57008339e7537f033b67cf84"}, {$pull: {"urls": "2.html"}}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

[`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) documentation