# removing an object from a mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document in `Mongodb` collection, where I want to `remove an object`, using `title` key.

I tried using `$unset`, but it only `removes the title key` not the object to which it belongs.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576b63d49d20504c1360f688"),
    "books" : [
        {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689"),
            "title" :"abc",
            "price" : 40
        },
        {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("575f9badada0500d192c53f4"),
            "title" : "xyz",
            "price" : 20
        },
        {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("57458224d86b3d1561150f17"),
            "title" : "def",,
            "price" : 30
        }
    ],
    "user_id" : "575570c315e27d13167dfc0d"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the **entire object** that contains the query object use db.remove() query.

For your case:

```
db.yourcollection.remove({"books.title": "abc"});
```

Please double check the format in which the element of array is referenced.
This removes the *entire object**s*** that contains the embedded query obj. To remove only a single object, provide it with another field to uniquely identify it.

If you only want to remove the object that contains the title field from the array but wants to **keep the object that contains the array**, then please use the $pull operator. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641895/3359432) answer will be of help.

Example: if you want to remove object

```
        {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689"),
            "title" :"abc",
            "price" : 40
        }
```

just from the array but **keep the parent** object like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576b63d49d20504c1360f688"),
    "books" : [
        {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("575f9badada0500d192c53f4"),
            "title" : "xyz",
            "price" : 20
        },
        {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("57458224d86b3d1561150f17"),
            "title" : "def",,
            "price" : 30
        }
    ],
    "user_id" : "575570c315e27d13167dfc0d"
}
```

use

```
db.mycollection.update(
    {'_id': ObjectId("576b63d49d20504c1360f688")}, 
    { $pull: { "books" : { "title": "abc" } } },
false,
true 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$unset` won't remove the object from an array. `The $unset operator deletes a particular field.`  [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/).

Use `$pull` instead.

> The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.

Try following query

```
db.collName.update({$pull : {books:{title:abc}}})
```

Refer [$pull-doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

And if... ¿Do I want to delete an object that is inside a document and not as an array?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576b63d49d20504c1360f688"),
    "books" : {
        "574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689": {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689"),
            "title" :"abc",
            "price" : 40
        },
        "575f9badada0500d192c53f4": {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("575f9badada0500d192c53f4"),
            "title" :"xyz",
            "price" : 20
        },
        "57458224d86b3d1561150f17": {
            "art_id" : ObjectId("57458224d86b3d1561150f17"),
            "title" : "def",
            "price" : 30
        }
    },
    "user_id" : "575570c315e27d13167dfc0d"
}
```

The solutions is this:

```
db.auctions.update(
    {'_id': ObjectId("576b63d49d20504c1360f688")},
    {$unset: {"books.574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689":
        {_id: "574e68e5ac9fbac82489b689"}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using pull.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

> $pull
>
> ```
> The $pull operator removes from an existing array all instances of a value or values that match a specified condition.
>
> The $pull operator has the form:
>
> { $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }
>
> To specify a <field> in an embedded document or in an array, use dot notation.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try in the mongo shell

> db.yourcollection.remove({books:[{title:'title_you_want'}]})

Careful with the braces.

Comment: I don't think this will work. I think you need to reference title as {"books.title": "abc"}