# Mongo $pull on arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wrote this query to delete the **agentName** and **agentNumber** from the array when a match is found. I don't know why its not working.

```
db.collection('departments').update({}, {$pull:{"agents" : {'agentNumber':xxxxx}}},function(err,result) {
  console.log("Agent Deleted successfully")
  console.log(err)
})
```

Here's the db:

```
{
"name": "xxx",
"departments": [
    {
        "departmentName": "Technical",
        "agents": [
            {
                "agentName": "xxx",
                "agentNumber": "xxx",
            },
            {
                "agentName": "xxx",
                "agentNumber": "xxxxx", // 5 x's
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function with

```
Customer.findOneAndUpdate({agentNumber: agentNumber}, {$pull:{agents : {agentNumber:xxxxx}}},function(err, data){
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).json({'error' : 'error'});
    }

    res.json(data);

  });
```

Or for a better understanding you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array) question.

Comment: didn't work. What exactly should i write in place of query. I can get **agentNumber** from the controller

Comment: by query i mean if you are having any condition like `{id: req.params.id}`. Something like this. If you arent passing any query ,then your code will look like `db.collection('departments').findOneAndUpdate({$pull:{"agents" : {'agentNumber':xxxxx}}},function(err,result) {//your functionality});`

Comment: I could get **agentNumber** as the query.  `db.collection('departments').update({"agentNumber": agentNumber}, {$pull:{"agents" : {'agentNumber':xxxxx}}},function(err,result) {
  console.log("Agent Deleted successfully")
  console.log(err)
})`

Comment: Put an err check also, i will edit  my answer upto your requirement, and then you can see.