# How to delete items of array based on object id list in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm stuck with this and I thought you could help me somehow, from the frontend  it arives me a list of numbers which contains the ids of the object to be removed, for instance :

```
{
  "user":"TEST",
  "conditionsToDelete":[1586513509594,1586513519698]
}
```

And my documents on mongo look like:

[image]

As you see there is a property named id on the document > conditionConfig > id

So this list which comes me from the front has this id's which I have to use in order to filter and delete  the matching objects.

How I can do it? I've been trying something like the following:

```
let resBusqueda = await this.conditionModel.find({ user: conditionsPack.user });
    resBusqueda.forEach(condicionPack => {
      let condicionesFiltradas = [];

      condicionPack.conditionConfig.forEach(condicion => {
        let idAnalizadoActualSubcondicion = conditionsPack.conditionsToDelete.indexOf(condicion.id);
        if (idAnalizadoActualSubcondicion == -1) {
          condicionesFiltradas.push(condicion);
        }
      });
      condicionPack.conditionConfig = condicionesFiltradas;
      condicionesFiltradas = [];
    });
```

I receive the Document and make some changes on it but how can I save them?

Ty in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB, remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array) Instead of two DB calls you can do it in one call using above link !!

Answer (score 1):

there is a good example in [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull). but this might be good enough for you:

```
db.YourModel.update(
    { }, // conditions that specify your user instance
    { $pull: { firstArray: { $in: arrayOfObjectIds }, secondArray: "single ID" } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

I brought you example for single element removal and for your case, array of elements to be removed.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me understand it better