# How to remove object from array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following document structure:

[image]

And am trying to figure out how to delete a single object from the 'saved array', using the id in the object to select it (eg id 4182 will delete the object and all its properties at index 0). This was my attempt but not sure how to target it properly (No errors, but nothing updated):

```
      let id = req.query.clicked_id;  
      console.log("\deleteSaved id:", id);  
   
      db.collection("users").updateOne(
         { username: config.username },
         { $unset: { id: id} }, 
            (err, data) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              console.log("Item deleted from DB: ", id, data.result.nModified);
              res.redirect("/saved");
      }) ;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the answer very clear in the ([MongoDB, remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array/15641895#15641895))

and my answer is

you can use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator in mongodb documentation
to pull element from array
you can use this query

```
      let id = req.query.clicked_id;  
      console.log("\deleteSaved id:", id);  
   
      db.collection("users").updateOne(
         { username: config.username },
         { $pull: {saved: { id: id } }, 
            (err, data) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
              console.log("Item deleted from DB: ", id, data.result.nModified);
              res.redirect("/saved");
      }) ;
```

this one will work fine

Comment: Thanks. That worked great. Just needed the extra closing bracket for the $pull operator.