# How to remove a field having a specified value from a MongoDB document?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is a given document in mongo db as below

```
{

"emailid": "xxx.gmail",

"user_devices": [],
"devices": [{
    "created_time": 1607153351,
    "token": 123
},
{
    "created_time": 1807153371,
    "token": 1345
}]

}
```

Here i want to remove the field inside devices ie
`"created_time": '', "token": '1345'`
here token value is known, so need to delete "created_time" along with "token" where output is like

```
{

"emailid": "xxx.gmail",

"user_devices": [],
"devices": [{
    "created_time": 1607153351,
    "token": 123
}]

}
```

I tried unset code like below

```
var myquery = { 'emailid': emailid , 'devices.token':1345};
        var newvalues = { $unset:{
        'devices.created_time':'',
        'devices.token':1345
        } };

and used 

updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res))
```

but it does not work. Can anyone tell how to remove this specified field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB, remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the object you want to remove is in an array, you have to use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) in this way:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "emailid": "xxx.gmail"
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "devices": {
      "token": 123
    }
  }
})
```

In this query you are telling mongo: "Remove -using `$pull`- one field from the array `devices` where `token` is `123`".

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3P3uKbZu4Sd)

Edit:

Also, if you want to remove only one field into objec within array and not the object itself, the you can use [`$[<identifier>]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to filter and then `$unset` like this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "emailid": "xxx.gmail"
},
{
  "$unset": {
    "devices.$[elem].created_time": ""
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "elem.token": 123
    }
  ]
})
```

In this query, using `arrayFilters` you can `$unset` only in the object where `token` is `123`. You can use `created_time` to filter if you want too.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FZce5uq9_Vk)