# Mongoose delete element from array in collection

Tags: arrays, mongoose, collections

i have a collection of Users like this

```
{
"user": {
    "_id": "6073fdff72556c02e8fb4509",
    "email": "XXX",
    "admin": "XXX",
    "feature": [
        {
            "_id": "6064579bc6b0510174c1395d",
            "brand": "XXX",
            "category": "XXX",
            "parent": "XXX",
            "features": "XXX",
            "createdAt": "2021-03-31T11:06:03.162Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-03-31T11:06:03.162Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "60645a1b213dea021c44e762",
            "brand": "XXX",
            "category": "XXX",
            "parent": "XXX",
            "features": "XXX",
            "createdAt": "2021-03-31T11:16:43.729Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-03-31T11:16:43.729Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "6066ed63db689b02a289d90f",
            "brand": "XXX",
            "category": "XXX",
            "parent": "XXX",
            "features": "XXX",
            "createdAt": "2021-04-02T10:09:39.322Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-04-02T10:09:39.322Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "606775e2fc48c7023e0a85e6",
            "brand": "XXX",
            "category": "XXX",
            "parent": "XXX",
            "features": "XXX",
            "createdAt": "2021-04-02T19:52:02.072Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-04-02T19:52:02.072Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "60677b6afc48c7023e0a85e7",
            "brand": "XXX",
            "category": "XXX",
            "parent": "XXX",
            "features": "XXX",
            "createdAt": "2021-04-02T20:15:38.038Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-04-02T20:15:38.038Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

}

this colelction is populated through a Schema like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const { isEmail, isStrongPassword } = require('validator') 

    const Schema = mongoose.Schema
    
    const userSchema = new Schema({
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Please enter a valid email'],
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true,
            validate: [isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email']
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Please enter a valid password'],
            validate: [isStrongPassword, 'At least 8 characters, 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 number, 1 symbol']
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            lowercase: true
        },
        features: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Feature'
        }
    })
//fire a function to hash password before save to db
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt()
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt)
    next()
})

//static method to login user
userSchema.statics.login = async function(email, password) {
    const user = await this.findOne({ email })
    if (user) {
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        if (auth) {
            return user
        }
        throw Error('Incorrect Password')
    }
    throw Error ('Incorrect Email')
}

const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)
module.exports = User;
```

I'm trying to remove an id from future array in the user collection. Thius is the controller I'm using

```
const delete_menu = (req,res) => {
    const featureId = new Feature(req.body)
    console.log(featureId._id);
    User.updateMany({}, {$pull:  {feature: [featureId.id]}}, (err, result) => {
            if (err) return console.log(err)
            res.json(result)

    })
}
```

I've tryed several way but alkways get this response and the collection is not affected. I'm still learning so probably I'm mssing an important piece.

```
    {
    "ok": 0,
    "n": 0,
    "nModified": 0
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB, remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array)

Comment: Just need to correct your query `{ $pull: { feature: { _id: featureId._id } } }`

Comment: thaks for the replay. Already tried the link solution, unfortunatly it doesn'twork. The feature field is and array of Id that once a request comes in will be popuplated from a different collection.

Comment: you just need to remove that ids from the `features` array right?

Comment: yes becouse I already have remevoed the feature itself from the feature collection. i was lloking to use Mongoose post hook but once I recieve the response the population has already took place and mongoose remove that feature from the response. on the other side the id is still present in mongodb user colection ander feature field array.

Comment: whats the issue query looks good, see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WzT2cpXawMh), check other possibilities, console body parameters.

Comment: sorry I'm still learning and your last comments is not clear to me. Be patient with me

Comment: can you point in my previous comment what is impatient? i am here to help you, i told you your query looks good and see other possibilities like your inputs request parameters and debug it.

Comment: sorry is a misundersting. I didn't want to say that you are impatient. It is just a a translation from italian that sounds ugly. Sorry for that. Apart fro that should it be that I'm behind am auth mechanism that requires authentication e nd jwt validation?

Comment: i'll try this, if it the right way of using it. https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rr4ne2iTKz9

Comment: you can use `$pullAll` instead of `$pull` to remove array of ids.

Comment: Do know what else to do. I'll try everythinf that comes out to my mind but I'm not ablke to figured out what happend. In the playgroud I'm able to do it while with postman nothing. Just the last thing. Could the populate operation affect the query?