# How can we delete an array index from a mongodb database with some conditions?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The following is the data in my mongodb database collection.

```
[   
    {
            _id: 6097ba8b64d60c653b810c28,
            pincode: 711104,
            mailID: [ 
                 {
                    mail: "email1@gmail.com",
                    dateOfReg: "10-05-2021"
                 },
                 {
                    mail: "email2@gmail.com",
                    dateOfReg: "09-05-2021"
                 }
            ]   
    },
    {
            _id: 6097bb7c64d60c653b810c29,
            pincode: 841231,
            mailID: [ 
                {
                    mail: "email3@gmail.com",
                    dateOfReg: "09-05-2021"
                },
                {
                    mail: "email4@gmail.com",
                    dateOfReg: "08-05-2021"
                }
            ]   
    },   
    {
            _id: 6097bbaa64d60c653b810c2a,
            pincode: 711105,
            mailID: [ 
                {
                    mail: "email6@gmail.com",
                    dateOfReg: "07-05-2021"
                }
            ]   
    } 
]
```

And I want to delete the indexes of array **mailID** in which **dateOfReg: "09-05-2021"**

I have tried to solve this problem with following command which I found in mongodb docs.

```
vaccinenotifier.update({},
    {
      $pull: {
        mailID: {
          $elemMatch: {
            dateOfReg : "10-05-2021"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { multi: true })
```

But its not doing the job. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB, remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array)

Comment: Yeah thanks, its working fine,  but it was incomplete i think, to execute my i operation I had to use **.exec()** after update() function.

Comment: no exec() is not compulsory, without it you can execute query, exec() will give you deep level explanation of error.