# Find an object that can be in different arrays and delete it MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have the following document:

```
{
_id: "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd8",
companies:{
   apple: [
       {
        product_id: "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd7"
       },
       {
        product_id: "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd6"
       }
   ],
   microsoft: [
       {
        product_id: "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd5"
       },
       {
        product_id: "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd4"
       }
   ]
  }
}
```

How can I find and delete the object with the `product_id: "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd4"`.

P.S: I use MongoDB native driver for Nodejs.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [MongoDB, remove object from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641492/mongodb-remove-object-from-array), you can use `findOneAndUpdate` method.

Comment: @turivishal - But if I don't know the name of the array? I want to find the object by product_id, but I don't know the name of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *If I don't know the name of the array? I want to find the object by `product_id`*

It is not possible with regular update query, you can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$objectToArray` convert `companies` object to array in key-value format
- `$map` to iterate loop of above converted array
- `$filter` to filter dynamic array's by `product_id`
- `$arrayToObject` convert key-value array to regular object format

```
let product_id = "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd4";
YourSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: "609bcd3160653e022a6d0fd8" }, // put your query
  [{
    $set: {
      companies: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$companies" },
            in: {
              k: "$$this.k",
              v: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$$this.v",
                  cond: { $ne: ["$$this.product_id", product_id] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  {    
    new: true // return updated document
  }
);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jJjJLr_n03g)

Comment: Thank you so much! That's the answer!