# MongoDB Unsetting a Sub document

Tags: mongodb

Give the following document:

```
{
'order_id': 'H2x3g',
'user_id': 777,
'total': [ {
        'date': ISODate("2015-06-09T00:00:00.0Z"),
        'total': 4
    }, {
        'date': ISODate("2015-06-10T00:00:00.0Z"),
        'total': 1
    } ]
}
```

How can I delete or unset only the entry for `2015-06-09` ?

Comment: See the [**`$pull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator in the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048424/removing-specific-items-from-array-with-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) check query as below :

```
db.collectionName.update({"order_id":"H2x3g","total":{"$elemMatch":{"date":ISODate("2015-06-09T00:00:00Z")}}},
                         {"$pull":{"total":{"date":ISODate("2015-06-09T00:00:00Z")}}})
```

Comment: I need to filter by `order_id` as well, how can add that to the condition you wrote?