# mongoose - remove element in array using $pull

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a node object that looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":"58b336e105ac8eec70aef159",
   "name":"my node",
   "ip":"192.168.1.1",
   "__v":0,
   "configuration":{
       "links":[
         {
            "linkName":"athena_fw_listen_tcp_5555",
            "_id":"58b336e105ac8eec70aef15d",
            "local":true
         },
         {
            "linkName":"athena_fw_listen_udp_5554",
            "_id":"58b336e105ac8eec70aef15c",
            "local":true
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am sending a delete request to my express server that looks like this:
`DELETE http://localhost:9000/api/nodes/58b336e105ac8eec70aef159/links/58b336e105ac8eec70aef15d`

I followed instructions in [$pull mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) and I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048424/removing-specific-items-from-array-with-mongodb)

But it does not seem to work, as I keep receiving: `500 (Internal Server Error)`

This is how the code on my express side looks like:

```html
exports.destroyLink = function(req, res) {
    Node.findById(req.params.id, function(err, node) {
        if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        if (!node) { return res.status(404).send('Not Found'); }
        console.log("Node", JSON.stringify(node))
        console.log("Params", req.params)

        node
            .update({ '_id': req.params.id }, { $pull: { 'configuration': { 'links': { '_id': req.params.linkId } } } }, false, true)
            .then(err => {
                if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
                return res.status(204).send('No Content');
            });
    })
};
```

The express router contains this:
`router.delete('/:id/links/:linkId', controller.destroyLink);`

So I am expecting id and linkId as params, I use id (`_id: req.params.id`) to target a specific node and linkId (`_id: req.params.linkId`) to target a specific link, but it doesn't work!

Need help resolving the issue, I don't know what I am missing here!

Comment: Can you try  `{ $pull: { 'configuration.links': { '_id': req.params.linkId }  }  }` ?

Comment: @Veeram I tried what you suggested before and I tried it now, but it does not work! :'(
I updated my line of code to this:
`node.update({ '_id': req.params.id }, { $pull: { 'configuration.links': { '_id': req.params.linkId } } }, function(err, data) {
            console.log("Data", data)
            if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
            return res.status(204).send('No Content');
        });`

this what I get in the console: `Data { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }`

Comment: okay  not sure how to fix it as is. On  a side note, `configuration` key is redundant in your document. You can remove it if it works for you and then you can access `links` as mentioned in docs.

Comment: Oh, that's because I am planning on adding other elements to `configuration`, so I would prefer keeping it this way. Thank you anyways, I appreciate it!

Comment: You are welcome. So I looked into further. I don't much about mongoose. You can verify the `_id` is defined as `String` in your mongoose schema. If it is defined as `ObjectId` then you have to convert `req.params.id` and `req.params.linkId` into `ObjectId` before passing it to query. Btw the query edit I suggested above works fine from mongo shell.

Comment: I tried converting the parameter to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. As far as I understand from this line below, the delete request was accepted and successful.
`DELETE /api/nodes/58b356a18f54358c5b9c2123/links/58b356a18f54358c5b9c2127 204 13ms`
However, the node object appears to still have the link_to_delete in its 'configuration.links' array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hi all and thank you for your help. I finally got it to work!!!

After almost 3 hours of troubleshooting :'( :'( this is the solution that used:

```
exports.destroyLink = function(req, res) {
Node.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id, { $pull: { "configuration.links": { _id: req.params.linkId } } }, { safe: true, upsert: true },
    function(err, node) {
        if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        return res.status(200).json(node.configuration.links);
    });
};
```

Instead of `findById` then update the node, I did both using `findByIdAndUpdate`. It' working perfectly now!!!

I still don't find an explanation for the other version though. But anyways glad it's working this way.

Comment: Thanks, after spending lots of time your answer resolved my issue . To make findByIdAndUpdate work I had to set useFindAndModify to false ( mongoose.connect(uri, { useFindAndModify: false }); )

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue getting a query like yours working. I think your query is not finding the id you're looking for. If you want to find an object in mongo by '_id' it needs to be passed in as an ObjectId. Try modifying things so it looks like this:

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
var oId = new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id);
update({ '_id': oId }, { $pull: { 'configuration': { 'links': { '_id': req.params.linkId } } } }, false, true)
```

Comment: I tried converting the parameter to both `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` and as you suggested above `mongo.ObjectID`. As far as I understande from this line below, the delete request was accepted and successful.
`DELETE /api/nodes/58b356a18f54358c5b9c2123/links/58b356a18f54358c5b9c2127 204 13ms`
However, the node object appears to still have the link_to_delete in its 'configuration.links' array.

Answer (score 1):

I never got this working using the mongodb `$pull` operator. An alternative is to find the document then update the array using the mongoose `pull` method. The `pull` method can take an id string as its single argument and knows how to handle it. For this example using promises the code would look something like:

```
exports.destroyLink = function(req, res) {
  Node.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(node => {
      node.configuration.links.pull(req.params.linkId)
      return node.save()
    .then(node => res.send(node.configuration.links))
}
```

[The mongoose docs for `pull`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.pull)

Answer (score 0):

I got the .update mongoose function to work by changing to this:

```
{ $pull: { 'configuration': { 'links': { '_id': ''+req.params.linkId+'' } } } }
```

Once you concatenate that, it'll pull it from the array.

Answer (score 0):

For my problem, this worked

await FormSchema.updateOne({formName: name}, {$pull: {fields: {fieldName: fieldName}}}).exec();

and here is what my schema looks like

```
{
"fields": [
    {
        "contentType": "Text",
        "fieldName": "First Name",
        "textType": "short",
        "isUnique": false
    },
    {
        "contentType": "Boolean",
        "fieldName": "Contact Me"
    }
],
"_id": "61f71efd14cafb5a50ba365f",
"formName": "Contact",
"__v": 4
```

}