# How to delete a specific sub-document from an array field in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

well i've been working on a project and i want to delete an item inside an array in mongodb. 
here is my code

```
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    await categoryCollection.findOne({_id : ObjectID(this.category_id)}, async (err, cat) => {
        let x = this.cat_slug
        if(!err) {
            cat.sub_categories.forEach(function(s_cat) {
                if (s_cat.slug == x) {
                    // here i need to delete the array
                }
            })
        } else {
            reject(err)
        }
    })
})
```

}

and my mongodb collection as an exemple

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e89db06a4c8d06b8b8784ae"),
"author" : ObjectId("5e89db06a4c8d06b8b8784ad"),
"name" : "Design",
"slug" : "design",
"sub_categories" : [ 
    {
        "author" : ObjectId("5e89e3914ebca9658b4bdae4"),
        "name" : "Games",
        "slug" : "games",
        "created_at" : "2020-4-5-6:55:38",
        "updated_at" : "2020-4-5-6:55:38"
    }, 
    {
        "author" : ObjectId("5e89e39c4ebca9658b4bdae5"),
        "name" : "Photoshop",
        "slug" : "photoshop",
        "created_at" : "2020-4-5-6:55:38",
        "updated_at" : "2020-4-5-6:55:38"
    }
],
"created_at" : "2020-4-5-5:56:55",
"updated_at" : "2020-4-5-5:56:55"
```

}

i wanna delete one item in the `sub_categories` array and that item am going to select it from my template engine (button) when i click on the delete button i should delete a specific item like the sub_categories[0] item i wanna delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you.

```
categoryCollection.update(
  { _id : ObjectID(this.category_id) },
  { $pull: 
    { 'sub_categories': 
      { "author": ObjectId("5e89e3914ebca9658b4bdae4") }
    }
  } 
)
```

It will work only if "author" is unique.
If not. Add unique id for every "sub_categories".

Comment: For more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048424/removing-specific-items-from-array-with-mongodb